# How to prove $\int_0^\infty xdF = \int_0^\infty 1-F dx$

Tags: real-analysis, probability

I want to prove the following proposition.

Proposition: Let $F:[0,∞]→[0,1]$ be  monotonically non-decreasing , $\lim_{x\to\infty}F(x)=1$ and $\int_0^\infty xdF < ∞$ . Then $\int_0^\infty 1-F dx =J< ∞$ and $\int_0^\infty xdF = \int_0^\infty 1-F dx$

I can prove that for every $u≧0$ ,  $\int_0^u xdF - \int_0^u 1-F dx = (1-F(u))u$. I think that $(1-F(u))u<|J-\int_0^u xdF|$ , so $u(1-F(u))\rightarrow 0\space(u\rightarrow\infty)$. However I cannot prove this. please help me.

Comment: It is simply the fact from probability theory that $\mathsf E(X)=\int_0^\infty \mathsf P(X>x)\,\mathrm dx$ for $X\geq0$

Answer (score 1):

[image]Hint:

$\int_{0}^{\infty}1\ dx$ gives an area of rectangle with length $\infty$ and width $1$.

$\int_{0}^{\infty}F\ dx$ gives area of a region in the rectangle below curve $F$

$\int_{0}^{1}x\ dF$ gives area of a region in the rectangle above curve $F$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That is why I guess $(1-F(u))u<|J-\int_0^u xdF|$. I want a hint for this inequality if this is true.

Comment: @Saito hey mate, for that check out the picture i just attached.

Answer (score 0):

Using integration by parts, with $u=1-F$, $du=-dF$, $dv=dx$, and $v=x$, we obtain
$$\int_0^{\infty}(1-F)dx=x(1-F)|_0^\infty-\int_0^{\infty}x(-dF)$$
$$=\int_0^{\infty}xdF$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to prove $x(1-F(x))|_0^u\rightarrow0\space(u\rightarrow\infty)$. What is the reason for this convergence?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} xdF(x)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\left( 1-F(x)\right)dx$$

Note that we can rewrite $x$ as:

$$x=\int_{0}^{x}dy$$

Than we get:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}xdF=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{x}dy dF$$

Switching the order of the double integral we get

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{x}^{\infty}dF dy$$

The inner integral is:

$$\int_{x}^{\infty}dF=\overline{F}(x)=1-F(x)=P\left[X>x\right]$$

and we finally get that

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\left( 1-F(x)\right)dx=\int_{0}^{\infty} xdF(x)$$

as required.